# Convert Java uni code to HTML base unicode

Tags: java, android, html, unicode

I am developing an android app.

I am getting below string from database and I want to display it in webview control of android:-

```
<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title><\/title>\n\t<\/head>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">\n\t\t\t<strong><img alt=\"\" height=\"318\" src=\"http:\/\/demo.com\/uploads\/ckeditor\/.jpg\" style=\"margin: 20px; float: right;\" width=\"376\" \/>\u0ab5\u0ab0\u0acd\u0ab7 \u0ae8\u0ae6\u0ae6\u0aeb\u0aae\u0abe\u0a82 \u0ab2\u0ac0\u0a82\u0aac\u0aa1\u0ac0\u0aa8\u0abe \u0aa6\u0a82\u0aaa\u0aa4\u0ac0\u0a8f \u0aef.\u0aeb\u0aeb \u0ab2\u0abe\u0a96 \u0aaa\u0aa1\u0abe\u0ab5\u0acd\u0aaf\u0abe \u0aac\u0abe\u0aa6 <\/p>\n\t<\/body>\n<\/html>
```

To display this in webview i have used below code to display above html code:-

```
Wbeview webNewsDetail = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webDetail);
webNewsDetail.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webNewsDetail.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webNewsDetail.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webNewsDetail.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Above String", "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

But it display as below image:-
[image: WebView Image]

I search and google it and I came to know that above mentioned unicode(\u0ab5) is of Java,c or c++ base and HTML support only &#______ (Ex:- &#fffff).

Now My question is:-
How can i convert java base unicode to html base unicode using java?
 or 
How can i display that string in webview directory without converting HTML base unicode?

Please help me, I am stuck from last 2 days.

Appriciate your time.

Comment: From google searching "convert java unicode to html unicode" http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html

Comment: Note also the escaped slashes, tabs and newlines. Are you sure this is the actual string, and not some representation?